# Angular - returning value from inside 'then'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them match my specific problem:

I have a TypeScript function in an Angular 6 service, calling a function in another service like this:

**Service1:**

```
myArray: Array<IMyInterface>

...

getArray(): Observable<IMyInterface[]> {

    this.myArray= this.service2.getAnArray(1);
    return Observable.of(this.myArray);
}
```

**Service2**

```
getAnArray(myEntityId): Array<IMyInterface> {
  const myArray2: IMyInterface[] = [];

  this.getConnection().then(connection => {
    connection.invoke('GetEntityById', myEntityId).then((someJson: any) => {
      someJson.forEach( x => myArray2.push(x));       
      return myArray2;
    })
  }); 
}
```

It gives me the error in Service2 `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

I need to return `myArray2` *after* `connection.invoke('GetEntityById', myId)` has resolved, as the array is only populated after that resolves, which is why I try to do it inside `then`.

How do I do this?

Comment: may be you can add `myArray` on component instance like `this.myArray` and use it wherever you want in component rather than returning it?

Comment: return connection as well?

Comment: No, thanks but neither of those work. I've updated the question with more details of the context. The connection shouldn't be returned from Service2, as it's important that any use of it is strictly encapsulated in Service2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

This may/may not suit your needs, but you could just return the `Promise` from your service method, eg:

```
getAnArray(myEntityId) {
  const myArray: IMyInterface[] = [];

  // Note the return here
  return this.getConnection().then(connection => {
    return connection.invoke('GetEntityById', myEntityId).then((someJson: any) => {
      someJson.forEach( x => myArray.push(x));       
      return myArray;
    })
  }); 
}
```

Your calling code would then look like

```
getAnArray(someId).then(function(theArray) {. . .});
```

Comment: I think another `return` is missing before `connection.invoke`.

Comment: No, getAnArray isn't a promise

Comment: Then what you want to do isn't really possible I don't think. If you're relying on asynchronous behavior, I don't know of a graceful way to convert that to synchronous behavior  for calling code outside of async/await which is just promises anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for this. But someone may find this helpful.
You can use Async/Await for this. The reason is every time 'await' occurs, it will hold the thread until the job is done.

```
 async getAnArray(myEntityId) {
    await this.getConnection();
    try {
      let result = await connection.invoke('GetEntityById', myEntityId).then((someJson: any) => {
      someJson.forEach(x => myArray.push(x));
      return myArray;
      })
   } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

}

To get results (will return a promise):

```
this.getAnArray(myEntityId).then((data) => {
  console.log('data' , data);
 
});
```